# Deploy caffe regression model

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have trained a regression network with `caffe`. I use `"EuclideanLoss"` layer  in both the train and test phase. I have plotted these and the results look promising.

Now I want to deploy the model and use it. I know that if `SoftmaxLoss` is used, the final layer must be `Softmax` in the deploy file. What should this be in the case of `Euclidean loss`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deploy you only need to discard the loss layer, in your case the `"EuclideanLoss"` layer. The output of your net is the `"bottom"` you fed the loss layer.

For `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer (and `"SigmoidCrossEntropy"`) you need to **replace** the loss layer, since the loss layer includes an extra layer inside it (for computational reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I ran the deploy and I have a small question: is it possible for caffenet to adjust labels? I use floats of values 40, 80 and 120 (and expect data in between these values), but I get predictions of 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10. Could caffenet simply divide these values by 10?

Comment: @user4039874 I don't suppose caffe is scaling data without you explicitly knowing about it/controling it.

Comment: Alright, then there is most likely a problem somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user4039874 Euclidean loss can be tricky sometimes, especially when large numbers are invloved. Try [smooth L1 loss](https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn/blob/bcd9b4eadc7d8fbc433aeefd564e82ec63aaf69c/src/caffe/layers/smooth_L1_loss_layer.cu)