# PyCaffe output layer for testing binary classification model

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, convolution, pycaffe

I fine tunes vgg-16 for binary classification. I used sigmoidLoss layer as the loss function.

To test the model, I coded a python file in which I loaded the model with an image and got the output using :

out = net.forward()

**My doubt is should I take the output from Sigmoid or SigmoidLoss layer.
And What is the difference between 2 layers.**

My output will actually be the probability of input image being class 1.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making predictions on test set, you can create a separate deploy prototxt by modifying the original prototxt.

Following are the steps for the same

- Remove the data layer that was used for training, as for in the case of   classification we are no longer providing labels for our data.
- Remove any layer that is dependent upon data labels.
- Set the network up to accept data.
- Have the network output the result.

You can read more about this here: [deploy prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Using-a-Trained-Network:-Deploy)

Else, you can add 
 include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }

to your SigmoidWithLoss layer so that it's not used when testing the network. To make predictions, simply check the output of Sigmoid layer.

Answer (score 1):

`SigmoidWithLoss` layer outputs a **single** number per batch representing the loss w.r.t the ground truth labels.

On the other hand, `Sigmoid` layer outputs a probability value for each input in the batch. This output **does not** require the ground truth labels to be computed.

If you are looking for the probability per input, you should be looking at the output of the `Sigmoid` layer

Comment: what does SigmoidWithLoss layer's output represents during testing, since there is no ground-truth label.

Comment: @ShivamDuggal see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39018076/1714410). You cannot have `"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"` layer without ground truth. the layer **must** have two inputs.